# Easiest way or lightlest library to get bigrams and trigrams in Java?

Tags: java, text

I'd rather not have to fire up lingpipe if possible which leaves me wondering if there are any quick, easy ways in java to extract all the bigrams and trigrams from a string of text?

thanks

Comment: More context please. Show some input and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always the easiest way is to use an existing library. You can take a look on [simmetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) library. You can also use [lucene NgramTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/package-summary.html). You can also implement this algorithm yourself. First, You have to find all words (using [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)) in the text and than generate [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class NGramIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    String[] words;
    int pos = 0, n;

    public NGramIterator(int n, String str) {
        this.n = n;
        words = str.split(" ");
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return pos < words.length - n + 1;
    }

    public String next() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = pos; i < pos + n; i++)
            sb.append((i > pos ? " " : "") + words[i]);
        pos++;
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### solution for Bigrams

The string str is initialized with the words "I am sample string and will be tokenized on space". The string is then broken into tokens using StringTokenizer which returns array of strings  e.g. "I", "am", "sample" etc...

A check is made to make sure the string array contains at least 2 words since a word cant make a bigram. So then you iterate through the string array, **if it is the first time running through the while loop, the string s1 is initialised to the first element in the string array. Then string s2 is initialised to the second element in the array, and s1 and s2 are joined together to form s3 which is pushed to the arrayList.**

`s1 = "I";`
`s2 = "am"`
`s3 = s1 + " " + s2; //makes s3 = "I am"`

After that, the value that was in s2 is set to s1, and s2 is set to an empty String. This makes the last(second) element in a bigram move to the first position making space for another element to occupy s2 in the next iteration. When you now iterate through the rest array only s2 will be assigned a value.

```
import java.util.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String str = "I am sample string and will be tokenized on space";
        ArrayList<String> bigrams = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(str);
        if(itr.countTokens() > 1)
        {
            System.out.println("String array size : " + itr.countTokens());
            String s1 = "";
            String s2 = "";
            String s3 = "";
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                if(s1.isEmpty())
                    s1 = itr.nextToken();
                s2 = itr.nextToken();
                s3 = s1 + " " + s2;
                bigrams.add(s3);
                s1 = s2;
                s2 = "";
            }

        }
        else
            System.out.println("Tokens is 1 or 0");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < bigrams.size()) 
        {
            System.out.println(bigrams.get(i));
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of your code and fix your indenting.

Comment: @mypetlion just fixed a few things and explained it a bit. Thanks for telling me!!